# How to get scrolling transitions in OSX terminal?

Tags: macos, vim, terminal

How can I get the terminal (or Visor/TotalTerminal) to smoothly scroll when it prints out text. So that I don't completely lose my sense of location when for instance showing git diffs. Or, when navigaiting long diffs in vim-mode using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd>. I don't want the terminal to "jump" to a new place, but rather smoothly flow to it.

(I'm using osx snow leopard)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.

Terminal emulators work with lines and characters as their smallest units, not your display's pixels.

Consider each individual character as your terminal's pixel: just as your display can't show half pixels, your terminal can't show 1/2 or 1/4 or 1/8 of a character.

Smooth scrolling is the norm in GUI land because text (or any meaningful piece of information) is usually a lot taller than 1 pixel. You can hide parts of it without losing too much information. Up to a certain threshold, of course.

In CLI land, the smallest display unit is also the smaller bit of information. It's either there or not there.

So, smooth scrolling — pixel by pixel — doesn't really make sense *and* doesn't seem to be a trivial thing to implement.

Comment: Thanks for that enlightening, yet disheartening, answer. Do you think it would be possible with a terminal emulator like [TermKit](https://github.com/unconed/TermKit/)?

Comment: What about semi-smooth transitions in terminal (scrolling transitions line by line)? Could it maybe be done by a bash script, like [some have done](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2183) for vim ?

Comment: Maybe it can be done. The linked script doesn't work at all for me and the other one linked on that page works more or less but does crazy things like inserting dozens of `jjjjjjjjjj`. Anyway, I find that kind of scrolling horrible, gratuitous and distracting. What would be the situation where that would be useful?

Comment: DEC VT330/340 green-screen terminals had smooth scrolling that scrolled the screen a pixel at a time, so a true emulator should incorporate this feature. Each standard character cell was 10 pixels high so each line appeared at the bottom of the screen one tenth of a character at a time. Being a hardware feature rather than software, it was incredibly smooth even by today's standards and I really miss it when working in the terminal. The code to enable it was CSI ? 4 h and to disable CSI ? 4 l (that's lowercase L) where CSI is character 233.